# TypeORM cyclic dependency with OneToOne and ManyToOne

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I've got these two entities related to each other:

```js
@Entity()
export class Message {

    // ... other columns ...

    @OneToMany(() => Action, action => action.message, { eager: true, cascade: true })
    public actions: Action[];
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class Action {

    // ... other columns ...

    @ManyToOne(() => Message, message => message.actions, { nullable: false })
    public message?: Message;
}
```

But I want to record on the message entity when the user takes an action. I try adding an extra relation to the message like this:

```js
@Entity()
export class Message {

    // ... other columns ...

    @OneToMany(() => Action, action => action.message, { eager: true, cascade: true })
    public actions: Action[];

    @OneToOne(() => Action, { nullable: true })
    @JoinColumn()
    public action_taken: Action;
}
```

But when trying to save a new message with the `actions` relation populated (trying to save them all at once with `cascade: true`), then I get the following error:

```sh
TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: "Action"
    at new TypeORMError (/app/node_modules/typeorm/error/TypeORMError.js:9:28)
    at visit (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:144:23)
    at visit (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:160:21)
    at visit (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:160:21)
    at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.toposort (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:139:17)
    at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.sort (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:53:45)
    at SubjectExecutor.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectExecutor.js:99:124)
    at step (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
    at /app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:75
```

Setting `cascade: false` doesn't throw the error, but then it also doesn't save the related records.

What am I missing? Is there a way I can still have `cascade: true` and have a double relation to an entity? Or will I have to manually save the related records?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: No, I ended up just manually storing the id to `action_taken`. It takes extra queries on retrieving the data, but it's the only way I could get it to work with TypeORM.

Comment: You can solve that by adding two different entities relating to the same table. If you do that also set one entity to synchronize=false so that you don't run into issues when typeorm is synchronizing your DB.

Comment: Do mention the database you are using. as it's working fine with Postgres,MSSQL and MYSQL 

Not working with SQLite expo

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue, working fine on nest CLI but give issues using serverless and webpack. Typeorm does not work well with webpack. I used repository.save (entity) and always failed with cyclic dependency.

After switching to

```
repository.createQueryBuilder()
.insert()
.values(data)
.execute();
```

This error has been cleared. I really recommend trying to change the repository method, because the save() method waits for the full entity set and createQueryBuilder() takes the entity values and turns them into string values, making a normal query.

Comment: Same here. Working in local with ts-node, Problem with serverless.

Answer (score -2):

Had this problem, in a `@ManyToOne` `@OneToMany` relationship, It can be solved by removing the side of the relationship that is without `cascade`. The error goes away, and the cascade works.

Comment: It's working with the development build, when we generate the production build it's not working

For Expo typeorm with expo-sqlite